# Barplot in ggplot2 to show perctange of total in each bar and c

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data like this:

```
SupplyChain Value
 A     1000
 B     2000
 C     3000
```

I want to make a barplot that has the x axis as the "SupplyChain" and the y axis as the value, however, within the chart, have a perctange of total within each bar. For example, in the chart for bar A it would 16.67% aswell as the top of the bar going to value "1000"

Also, I have a set of colors that I want to assign each Supplychain too, I have tried using "scale_colour_manual" within the ggplot but I am having no luck. Here is an example of what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way -

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  mutate(Percentage = paste(round(prop.table(Value) * 100, 2), '%')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(SupplyChain, Value)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = Percentage), vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]